# Visual Studio profiler won't instrument a C# program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

They have changed the profiler since the last time I dug into it and now I can't get anywhere.

I'm trying to use the instrumentation as it shows me how it got to the lines that are the bottleneck.  Unfortunately, I get "No code to instrument.  All selected functions are small functions."  There's exactly one option in the settings "Exclude small functions"--and the status of this makes no difference.  And, amazingly, putting the error message into Google returns zero hits.  And I'm simply specifying the program to profile, there are certainly some functions in there that are not "small" by any reasonable definition.

VS 2022 community version, I do not think I've used the profiler since I installed this version.